# APR for a Loan Paid Off Monthly

Tags: loans, interest-rate, apr

A loan is issued for 12 months for 1000 and is paid back with monthly payments of $140 each month.  Does this loan have an APR of 68%?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The periodic rate (here, the interest charged per month), as you would enter into a finance calculator is 9.05%. Multiply by 12 to get 108.6% or calculate APR at 182.8%. Either way it's far more than 68%.

If the $1680 were paid after 365 days, it would be simple interest of 68%. For the fact that payment are made along the way, the numbers change.

Edit - A finance calculator has 5 buttons to cover the calculations:
[image]

N = number of periods or payments

%i = the interest per period

PV = present value

PMT = Payment per period

FV= Future value

In your example, you've given us the number of periods, 12, present value, $1000, future value, 0, and payment, $140. The calculator tells me this is a monthly rate of 9%. As Dilip noted, you can compound as you wish, depending on what you are looking for, but the 9% isn't an opinion, it's the math. TI BA-35 Solar. Discontinued, but available on eBay. Worth every cent.

Per mhoran's comment, I'll add the spreadsheet version.

[image]

I literally copied and pasted his text into a open cell, and after entering the cell shows,

[image]

which I rounded to 9.05%. Note, the $1000 is negative, it starts as an amount owed.

And for Dilip - 1.0905^12 = 2.8281 or 182.8% effective rate. If I am the loanshark lending this money, charging 9% per month, my $1000 investment returns $2828 by the end of the year, assuming, of course, that the payment is reinvested immediately. The 108 >> 182 seems disturbing, but for lower numbers, even 12% per year, the monthly compounding only results in 12.68%

Comment: Good point; I was very sloppy, ignoring the payoff of principal along the way.

Comment: In the US, isn't the APR _defined_ in the Truth in Lending Act as the periodic rate times the number of times compounding is done each year and so the APR is 108.6%? Is it the Effective Annual Percentage Rate (EAPR) as defined in the European Union which is 182.8%?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Sorry, it looks to me like you're assuming compounding.  Isn't this not being compounded?

Comment: The 108% has no impact from compounding.

Comment: @Joe Sorry, where did you get the 9.05 from?

Comment: @user22347 I updated my answer.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Since you are in an updating mood, could you edit your answer to tell us how to **calculate APR at 182.8%**?? That number still puzzles me.

Comment: @DilipSarwate - really? done.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I respectfully disagree with your calculation in this particular situation. Yes, 9.05% per month compounds to a 182.8% annual rate if the loan is to be repaid in a single payment at the end of the year. But in this instance, there are 12 equal monthly payments that pay off the loan completely and this is not taken into account in your calculation of the APR as 182.8% (and is wrong as far as the legal definition of APR is in the US).

Comment: @DilipSarwate - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annual_percentage_rate for how/why I used that calculation. It's not how banks report in US, but, in my opinion, it's the return that the lender will actually see. I agree with you, it's not APR as used here.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I'm still not sure how this makes sense then.  It seems like there are companies actually charging this rate (108% APR) in many places, but this is an illegal rate.  How do companies manage to charge this then?

Comment: @user22347 - is 68% so much better? My credit cards are sub-20%, and HELOC (equity line), 2.5%.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Either way it's not for me, I'm just curious about why the amount is that.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer To clarify, the fact that it's a potentially illegal rate if that's the true rate leads me to believe there must be another way to calculate it so that it comes out lower.

Comment: @user22347 - false conclusion. The 108 I calculated was the rate that the bank/lender would state. Legal depends on your jurisdiction.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer The problem is the lender states it's about 46%, and yet every calculation I've come across (including my simple interest calculation) states it's higher.  I'm trying to find some way this could be 46%.

Comment: @user22347 - Tough to say. The fact that Chris and I offered the identical number, using independent calculations (and I actually offered 2 myself) suggests to me that there's no doubt. How can I guess at how someone else made an error? At least we understood the math behind your own first estimate of 68%.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Suppose we lend each other $1000. You, as lender, tell me that I am to pay you back in 12 equal monthly installments of $140 each and that, as per the Truth-in-Lending Act, the APR for this loan is 108.6%. But in your heart of hearts, you know that the APR is actually 182.6%. I, on the other hand, tell you that you must pay back $2828.10 at the end of the one year period and the APR is thus 182.6%, the same as the _actual_ APR (as opposed to the T-i-L-A mandated APR number) on the loan you are extending to me. So we are both satisfied that we earned 182.8% APR on our loans, right?

Answer (score 0):

If your APR is quoted as nominal rate compounded monthly, the APR is 108.6 %.

Here is the calculation, (done in *Mathematica* ).

The sum of the discounted future payments (p) are set equal to the present value (pv) of the loan, and solved for the periodic interest rate (r).

[image]

Details of the effective interest rate calculation can be found here.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation